# Jquery tools slide setting Effects

Tags: jquery, tabs, jquery-tools

Hello im using a slide based on Jquery tools , the problem is i need more effects than fade & slide.. is ther any list.. i really search in the documentation, maybe i didnt look well but really i didnt find it.. here is my code.. but I need the slide to move to the left, and the one after comes in moving from rigth to center, i really have bad english,, how this effect is called.. its very very common.. and simple i think.. i thought actually that was the "slide" movemnt any way..

Hope anyone can help me.

```
<script language="JavaScript">
    $(function() {
        $(".slidetabs").tabs(".images > div", {

            // enable "cross-fading" effect
            effect: 'slide',
            fadeOutSpeed: "slow",

            // start from the beginning after the last tab
            rotate: true

            // use the slideshow plugin. It accepts its own configuration
        }).slideshow();
    });
</script>
```

The effect on this slide : http://jquerytools.org/

I need it on this slide : http://jquerytools.org/demos/tabs/slideshow.html

Answer (score 0):

You can set a direction in Jquery UI slide as seen below

http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Effects/Slide

```
$("div").click(function () {
      $(this).hide("slide", { direction: "down" }, 1000);
});
```

Comment: thanks dude.. maybe my english its bad.. what i really need is jus tto apply The effect on this slide : http://jquerytools.org/

into this slide : http://jquerytools.org/demos/tabs/slideshow.html

Comment: The effect on this slide : http://jquerytools.org/

I need it on this slide : http://jquerytools.org/demos/tabs/slideshow.html

I just need to change the fade effect for the other effect, BUT I CANT